Human Body: question on Neufert drawing representing the Golden Ratio
Does anyone know what the right horizontal and curved doted lines (originating from the horizontal lines) mean in this drawing?  To the same, the drawing on the lower left corner, which has curved lines as well?
I understand each segment $M$ and $m$ are two lengths, when placed in a fraction represents to Golden Ratio $\phi$.  For instance, starting at the feet $\frac {M17 - M16} {M17} = \frac {M17} {M16} = \phi$.  I see that these seem to represent to lengths of the body facing forward and have suspicions that the curved lines that are dotted represent some changing value as the body is rotated in a circle, where the vertical pole between both legs is the axis of rotation.

Ref:
Neufert Architects Data 4th Edition
link to pic

This is certainly related to the famous "Vitruvian Man" by Leonardo da Vinci.

not commonly known:   the Vitruvian Man was to illustrate  a different system  of proportions for, the human figure. See book by physicist  Mario Livio,  https://dn720001.ca.archive.org/0/items/the-golden-ratio-the-story-of-phi-the-worlds-most-astonishing-number/The%20Golden%20Ratio_%20The%20Story%20of%20Phi%2C%20the%20World%27s%20Most%20Astonishing%20Number.pdf

Similar Le Corbusier's Modulor. A funny detail in the upper right corner of Neufert's sketch -- "man, the measure of all things" -- reminds me Schumacher's 'Small Is Beautiful'.

@m-stgt Thanks, read the initial part of Modulor.  I notice the drawing of the man with his hand up has what appears to be a belly/naval button, this appears to be M3/M2 in the above drawing.

Its a method to transfer oblique prportions to the rectangular grid for any characteristic point on the body by a compass.
The technique was developed by the Greek architects of the Apollon temple in Delphi and the Parthenon in Athens, where during the restauration in the last decades the schemas were detected on a large side wall in different local measures.
The realistic 'homo mensura' principle of the sophists has been propagated by the philosopher Protagoras, as such it has been critized by Sokrates in Platons dialog 'Protagoras'.
In art, all these drawings go back to the 'canon of Polykleitos', the creator of the most perfectly propotionated male bronces in the classical period, and Vitruvius, the author of Roman achitecture classics, from which Leonardo with his  Vitruvian man is drawing his own canon.

"It's a method to transfer oblique prportions to the rectangular grid for any characteristic point on the body by a compass.".  Where do I find out this method?  I searched for this and didn't find an answer.  I would like to apply it to this drawing to understand the oblique proportions as the body is rotated.

The triangle In the lower left  displays thr  $$Golden Ratio = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt 5)$$ (in German Goldener Schnitt (Cut)).  It has the proportions of the half big triangles, determined by foot base, crest and  horizontal  arm to the wrist joint.  With the circles any distance in the rectangular grid can be rotated to the golden diagonal, yielding  the complementary side of a golden rectangle

This doesn't answer my question.  I'm trying to understand what the curved doted lines (originating from the horizontal lines) mean in this drawing.  The suspicion was that the body is being rotated somehow.
